# Gmail sorting settings for Galaxy S4

Tags: gmail, 4.2-jelly-bean

Where is the setting to sort my gmail by read/unread on my new AT&T Galaxy S4? I was able to do it on the S3.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see this feature in the current version of Gmail (Sort by read/unread) However you can always remove the "Inbox" label from the message. This way your inbox will only show unread messages.